# Gridsome loses $page after change in the code

Tags: vue.js, gridsome

I am using gridsome with strapi.
After any change in the code code, when the page tries to re-render the new changes, i get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'strapi' of null"
```

The code i use:

`<h1>{{$page.strapi.recipes[0].Title}}</h1>`

The query:

```
<page-query>
query ($slug: String!) {
  strapi{
    recipes(where: {Slug: $slug}){
      Slug
      Title
      categories{
        Name
        Slug
      }
    }
  }
}
</page-query>
```

It loads the data again only when i restart the project with: **gridsome develop**